# Locale keeps resetting to English for non-sudo user account

Tags: linux-mint, locale

I have multiple regular user accounts running on Mint 17.1. `root` and `sudoers` are using the default language (in this case English), but the other accounts use different Languages. Every so often, users' `locale` reset to English, and will certainly happen after an `apt upgrade`. The way the users currently work around this is to open the terminal and run `locale`, log off and log back on.

Is there a permanent fix for my issue?

Comment: How do your users set their locale?  I would recommend that they put their desired settings into their `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login` which shouldn't be touched on by anything that happens system-wide.

Comment: @tink Will try that. Users set their own language via the GUI provided by Mint.

Comment: @tink Late reply but setting `LANG` did nothing

Comment: -  how about other LC variables, e.g. LC_ALL?   Btw, I find it odd that running `locale` should fix anything - all that does is to display values.